# Measuring how long the screen has been switched on

Tags: android, timer, screen

My English is not so good so I apologize in advance.

I want to make a timer that starts when the screen turned on. It should run until the screen turns off and then stop.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/01/timer.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice thread about handling screen on/off events: [Think Android](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/)

Instead of starting a timer I'd rather do this:

```
int seed;
int step = 1000; // Exactness of timer in ms
long start() {
    return (long) System.getCurrentTimeMillis()/step;
}
long read(long seed) {
    return ((long) System.getCurrentTimeMillis()/step) - seed;
}

if(/*screen on*/) {
    seed = start();
} else if(/*screen off*/) {
    Log.d("time", read(seed)*step + " ms");
}
```

I think working with a initial seed is more resource friendly and more easy than starting a "real" timer.

Answer (score 0):

When the screen turns off your activity calls **onPause()** method. In that method you can get [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and save it somewhere as a variable so you don't need to use timers or any other complicated methods. After your screen goes on with your active application the activity will call **onResume()** method where you get the second Unix time. Simply subtract these two variables, covert them to seconds and you are good to go.

Comment: This would change the result if he uses another app in the meanwhile... For a first testing ok, but not a nice solution, don't you think so too?

Comment: You are right. This is only usable if the user doesn't close or starts another app meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You need a broadcast receiver for the screen.

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "Receiver";
    private GregorianCalendar start, end;//or a long in ms

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            start = new GregorianCalendar();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            end = new GregorianCalendar();
        }
    }   
}
```

start it with:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    ScreenReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```